# Count characters within parentheses

Tags: excel, vba

How can adjust this so it only counts characters within parenthesis?

```
For c = 1 To lastRow
Cells(c + 1, 5).Value = Len(Cells(c + 1, 6).Value)
Next
```

The code that needs to be adjusted is:

```
Len(Cells(c + 1, 6).Value)
```

It should count everything within parenthesis (inclduing space). All the characters in column 5 looks like this: "GDK(x number of characters)". I want to count "x number of characters".

Comment: we are going to need more info on the characteristics of the inputs.  Some example inputs would be helpful.

Comment: That's a fairly vauge and useless question.  How about giving us some more information like how many pairs of paretheses, types of parentheses, nested parentheses?

Comment: All the characters in column 5 looks like this: "GDK(x number of characters)". I want to count "x number of characters". Updated initial post.

Comment: Find the positions of "(" and ")" and perform a subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### VBA Solution

You can create a `UDF` to `Split` your string by `"("` & `")"` where `Target` is your string input

```
'Note this should be placed in a Module
Public Function PCOUNT(Target As String) As Long

    PCOUNT = Len(Split(Split(Target, "(")(1), ")")(0))

End Function
```

which you can call directly from your worksheet or from your original macro like so:

```
For c = 1 to lastrow
    Cells(c + 1, 5) = PCOUNT(Cells(c + 1, 6))
Next c
```

---

### Non VBA Solutions

You can also do this without VBA by using either of the below equations where `A1` is your string input:

```
=SEARCH(")",A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)-1
=LEN(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,SEARCH(")",A1)))-1
```

Comment: To avoid error no 9 if the (left) bracket is omitted you could code : `PCOUNT = Len(Split(Split(s & "(", "(")(1) & ")", ")")(0))`

Comment: OP gave no indication that either bracket would ever be omitted so don't think that is needed... unless I misunderstand your comment @T.M.

Comment: Don't see my comment as critic: of course your solution is absolutely correct trusting consequent inputs. - My intention was to show a very easy method to hinder *any* possible error in advance by wrong inputs (i.e. missing bracket :-).

Comment: Wasn’t taken as criticism- I follow what you mean now. I’d use InStr to check that opening and closing parentheses are present before running. Good call @T.M.

Comment: `If InStr(Target, “(“) And InStr(Target, “)”) Then`